# returning matched element from array

Tags: perl

I would like to return an element of an array if it matches a pattern represented by a scalar. I would like to avoid looping so I've tried the following method:

use List::Util 'first';
my $match = first { /$pattern/ } @list_of_strings;

$match variable is not returning a value, even though, I know it matches exactly one element in array.  What am I doing wrong?

```
my @amplicon_exon = ();
        open(TXT5, "$amplicon_exon");
            while (<TXT5>){
                my $file_line = $_;
                $file_line =~ s/\s+\z//g;
                push (@amplicon_exon, $file_line);   
            }
        close(TXT5);

foreach (@amplicon_exon){
    chop($_);
}

my @matrix_lines = ();
        open(TXT5, "$matrixfile");
            while (<TXT5>){
                my $matrixlineentry = $_;
                $matrixlineentry =~ s/\s+\z//g;
                push (@matrix_lines, $matrixlineentry);   
            }
        close(TXT5);

        foreach (@matrix_lines){
    chop($_);
}
   my @failedamplicons = ();     
for my $vcf_file ( @vcf_files ) {

        $vcf_file =~ m|([^/]+)_annotated.vcf$| or die "Can't extract Sample ID";
         my $sample_id = $1;

         my @myuniquearray = ();
         my @amplicon_array = ();

        my $entire_matrix_header = $matrix_lines[0]; print "The matrix header is ".$entire_matrix_header."\n";
        $entire_matrix_header =~ s/\s+\z//g;
        my @matrix_headers = split (/\t/, $entire_matrix_header);
        push @matrix_headers, "endoffile";
        my $matrix_column_number = "";
        for (0..@matrix_headers){
                my $onco_matrix_header = $matrix_headers[$_];
                $onco_matrix_header =~ s/\s+\z//g;

                if ((length $onco_matrix_header > 0) && (index($sample_id, $onco_matrix_header) != -1)) {
                        $matrix_column_number = $_;
                        print "The matrixcolumnnumber is ".$matrix_column_number."\n";
                }
        }

        #print " The matrixcolumnnumber is ".$matrixcolumnnumber."\n";        


        for (1..@matrix_lines-1){
                my @matrix_values = split (/\t/, $matrix_lines[$_]);
                if ( ($matrix_values[$matrix_column_number]<201) && ($matrix_values[$matrix_column_number]>-1) ) {

                        my $f_amp = $matrix_values[1];#if ( grep( /^$value$/, @array ) )
                        print Dumper($f_amp, \@amplicon_exon);
                        my $match = first { /$f_amp/ } @amplicon_exon; print "#############the match is $match\n";
                        my @parts = split /:/, $match;
                        my $exon_amp = $parts[1]; my $gene_res = $parts[2];
                        print "less than 200 exists";

                         my @total_amps = ($run_folder, $sample_id, $gene_res, $exon_amp, $matrix_values[$matrix_column_number], $f_amp);
                         my $failedamplicon = join "\t", @total_amps;


                        push (@failedamplicons, $failedamplicon);
                }

        }

        for (0..@failedamplicons-1){
                my $failedamplicons = $failedamplicons[$_];
                open (MYFILE, ">>$failed_amps_output");##opens files with header and adds the rest of the lines.
                print MYFILE $failedamplicons."\n";
                close (MYFILE);
                }

        }
```

Sample data:

@amplicon_exon lines:

```
ON_MAP2K1_1:2:MAP2K1
OCP1_MAP2K1_1:3:MAP2K1
OCP1_MAP2K1_2:6:MAP2K1
```

$f_amp examples:

```
ON_MAP2K1_1
OCP1_MAP2K1_1
OCP1_MAP2K1_2
```

matrixfile

```
Gene   Target         barcode-1 barcode-2 barcode-3 barcode-4 barcode-5
MOTOR  Focus_MTOR_1    22        786       123       456       456
JAK1   OCP1_JAK1_2     345       45         342       23       432
ALT    OCP1_ALK_3      43        456        23        3         56
```

Comment: What is `$pattern` and what data is it matching?

Comment: Can you `use Data::Dumper;` and then `print Dumper(\@amplicon_exon);` to verify that your `@amplicon_exon` _really_ contains your pattern?

Comment: ...and do a `print ">$f_amp<\n";` to ensure that's what you think it is. ie. ensure there's no newlines or other surprises within it

Comment: Maybe your pattern contains meta characters and you need to `quotemeta` it or use `/\Q$f_amp\E/`.

Comment: *"I know it matches exactly one element in array"* I hope it's obvious that you're mistaken? The computer is vastly more likely to be correct than you are. Your Perl code is very awkward, but it's impossible to help you any further unless you provide more information. The output of `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($famp, \@amplicon_exon);` would help a lot. Have you read `@matrix_values` from a file and forgotten to `chomp` it?

Comment: What is `$pattern`? What's in the array you're supplying to `first`? Help us help you by creating a [mcve]!

Comment: $pattern is $f_amp and array is @amplicon_exon.

Comment: Although your edit is an improvement, it is still not a [mcve]. Please read that page and do what it says.

Comment: That doesn't look very minimal. Also, combining `\z` and `/g` makes no sense.

Comment: Dumper tells me that the $famp in in @amplicon_exon, however, $match is only returned 10% of the time. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

### *There is something wrong with part of the program that you haven't shown*

Here is a short program that uses exactly the `@amplicon_exon` values that you have given as examples, and dumps the result of the `first` call for every value of `$f_cmp`. It works

Perhaps this will shake you from your insistence that you have done nothing wrong?

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use List::Util 'first';
use Data::Dump;

# Using sample @amplicon_exon lines

my @amplicon_exon = qw/
    ON_MAP2K1_1:2:MAP2K1
    OCP1_MAP2K1_1:3:MAP2K1
    OCP1_MAP2K1_2:6:MAP2K1
/;

# Using $f_amp examples:

for my $f_amp (qw/
    ON_MAP2K1_1
    OCP1_MAP2K1_1
    OCP1_MAP2K1_2 / ) {

    my $match = first { /$f_amp/ } @amplicon_exon;

    dd $match;
}
```

#### output

```
"ON_MAP2K1_1:2:MAP2K1"
"OCP1_MAP2K1_1:3:MAP2K1"
"OCP1_MAP2K1_2:6:MAP2K1"
```

---

*I'd risk £5 that your `@matrix_values` contains newlines*

Comment: @user3781528: That's a guess. There's no way to tell for sure because for some reason you won't show us your data.

Comment: i've tried chop but it's not returning all of the matches. I've updated the code and included example of matrixfile. thanks

Comment: @user3781528: We are never going to fix this if you just keep adding tiny bits of information. Please put your *entire* program into your question, and upload your data files to Dropbox or Google Drive or similar and post links to them. That way we will be able to reproduce the problem ourselves and give you a rapid solution.